# How to run terminal window through PHP code

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to run new terminal window through my PHP code, and I have no clue how to do this.

I already tried:

```
<?php
     shell_exec("gnome-terminal");
?>
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: it didn't work isn't useful - what error did you get?

Comment: gnome-terminal is a gui terminal, so probably won't work with `shell_exec`. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to get a new terminal window in which I can type my commands. Which command do you suggest then?

Comment: That won't happen, not with PHP and shell_exec. This will attempt to create a terminal window **on the server**, not in the browser. If you want to use a shell terminal in your browser, there are several packages out there to emulate a terminal.

Comment: Sorry for my newbies question but which packages do you suggest? I tried to do it with shelljs back then, but I didn't know how to use it properly.

Comment: I don't use any of those packages, so I cannot recommend any,

Answer (score 2):

`shell_exec()` will execute shell command you provided and return it's output. It won't stay open, receive input from keyboard and similar.

It's crucial to understand how web server works. Your browser calls web server it generates the page, executes PHP if he finds any and returns the (HTML mostly) response. So you have one call and one response. There is no permanent connection between web browser and the server. You can't create console that easy.

Way to look at is maybe an AJAX call. I.e. you provide text area for typing the text, but when enter is pressed you call the server with AJAX call and pass entered text so it can be executed with shell_exec() or similar command.